# Parse JSON data from API

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am new to working with Jquery JSON and API's(this being my first Stack question, so please bear with me). So I am trying to figure out a way in which Im hitting a API and it will return data(city name) in JSON which I have to display on my page in list form. But the cities should be updated and the page should display the city names dynamically.

Here is the fiddle link:
[Fiddle File](https://jsfiddle.net/Nikhil_Mendonca/v2sppc7k/1/#&togetherjs=oPN1xOkB6V)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>TEST2</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button>Submit</button>
    <select id="list"></select>

</body>
</html>

<script type="text/javscript" src="jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javscript">

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'API HERE',

        data: { get_param: 'value' },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            $.each(data, function(index, element) {
                $('body').append($('list', {
                    text: element.detail
                }));
        });
            }
    });
</script>
```

JSON FILE

```
[
{"id":3,"detail":"Mumbai, Maharashtra, India"}, 
{"id":10,"detail":"Pune,Maharashtra, India"},
{"id":166,"detail":"Bengaluru"}
]
```

Requesting for your help, thanks in advance for those who contributed

Comment: I'm not certain which bit you're having trouble with, but I think what you're asking for is something like: `var json = JSON.parse(data.WhereverYourJSONIs)`, then iterate through that object building an HTML structure, and finally insert that into your `$('body').append()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided you receive data from API you can do what you want.

```
    //...
    success: function (data) {
        $.each(data, function(index, element) {
            //$('body').append($('list', {//no comment
            //    text: element.detail
            //}));
            //add cities to select id="list"
            $('<option/>') //create option
                 .val(element.id) //set its value
                 .text(element.detail) //set text
                 .appendTo('#list'); //and append to the list
        });//each
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to parse. JSON is JavaScript Object Notation. you can just asign data to variable and use it in your code like

```
    success: function(result) {
       var data = result;
   data.forEach(function(data){
   $('body').append($('list', {
                    text: element.detail
      }));
    }
    console.log(data);

    //in console you can see tyour data
    Object {type: "form-focus", element: "#run"}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is not a JSON object, its an array, are you sure it comes back like this? try to log it then do one of the following:

if it comes as a string write this

```
 $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'API HERE',

    data: { get_param: 'value' },
    dataType: 'json',
    accepts: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
    /* ... */
```

the accepts tells the server to send back json, hence you can get it as json. if it is still a string, write `JSON.parse(data)`

if it comes as an array like youve written, then there should be no problem, except that its an array not a json object. json should be an object not an array.

```
{results: [
{"id":3,"detail":"Mumbai, Maharashtra, India"}, 
{"id":10,"detail":"Pune,Maharashtra, India"},
{"id":166,"detail":"Bengaluru"}
]}
```

something like this will make it a json file.

if it comes like this, then you should write: `data.results` to access the array you need.